# Genital v. Genitals

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My reading shows that the plural form of the word **genital** is **genitals**.

However, I also find some users use the word **genitals** and **genital** interchangeably to represent the singular form of the word.

The word **genital** was used in [the following excerpt](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.plymouthherald.co.uk/news/plymouth-news/serial-flasher-told-keep-kit-5538027.amp):

> The court heard that Turner carried out a series of incidents between April and September of 2016 - all of exposure - which led to him being handed a Sexual Harm Prevention Order [SHPO] - banning him from exposing his genital in public, which he again breached, causing him to appear before the court.

The word **genitals** was used in [the following excerpt](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9116965/amp/Man-21-accused-exposing-genitals-woman-stopped-pat-dog-charged.html):

> Accused stalker, 21, is charged after 'exposing his genitals to a woman' when she stopped to pat his dog

According to the native English speaker, does the word **genitals** represent singular form of the word genital?

Example:

The accused unfastened his towel, exposing his genital/genitals.

Comment: The first story has an error. The man was "handed a Sexual Harm Prevention Order [SHPO] - banning him from exposing his genital in public". This should be 'genitals'. The second story uses 'genitals' correctly.

Comment: Better to copy and paste the text you are interested in, than just a link.

Comment: Incorrect use of 'excerpt'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is predicated on a typographical error. OP already knows (as mentioned in the question) that the proper form of the word is **genitals**.

Comment: The OP doesn't know that.  They say "My reading shows the plural form of genital is genitals".  They don't know the proper form of the word is genitals - that is their question!

Comment: Thank you james k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Genitals" is a noun that is always used in the plural form (if you have seen examples where "genital" is used as a singular noun, it is a typo or an error.

There are other nouns that are always plural: "clothes",  "earnings", "congratulations", "gallows" as well as the paired items "trousers", "scissors" and so on.

"Genital" can be used as an adjective: meaning "related to the genitals": "Genital area", "genital wart"

Comment: Sorry, that was also a typo or error!

Comment: Thank you james k. i appreciate it.